# Yii windows vs *nix при выгрузке на сервер 404 ошибка

Tags: windows, http-status-code-404, unix, php, yii

Суть вопроса.

Есть локальный сервак под виндой, все запросы на нем идут отлично. Обрабатываются все контроллеры и экшены, Но есть одно но.

при выгрузке всего этого дела на сервак под *nix один контроллер выпадает и не хочет работать. т.е. постоянно 404 ошибка при любом экшене.

```
class AjaxActionController extends CController// собственно так он называется.

public function actionAddToCard() 
public function actionAddOneProduct() // несколько экшенов.
```

и при запросе на серваке **ajaxaction/addtocard 404 error**

В общем непонятно в чем ошибка и почему она именно на серваке именно под *nix системой.

Регистр вообще не важен, что в верхнем, что в нижнем, одно и тоже 404.

Быть может кто-то сталкивался с таким?

ps часто сталкиваюсь с тем что при переносе с виндового сервака на unix получается лажа. Хотя регистр всех моделей, модулей учитывается!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Часто сталкивался с подобной проблемой когда писал код под под виндой, потом перешел на линукс. А теперь все просто - смотрите лог ./protected/runtime/application.log, что за ошибка и правьте.

Comment: 2012/11/07 16:47:29 [error] [exception.CHttpException.404] exception CHttpException with message 'Невозможно обработать запрос "ajaxaction/clearbasket".' in /var/www/somesite/data/framework/web/CWebApplication.php:280
    Stack trace:
    0 /framework/web/CWebApplication.php(135): CWebApplication->runController('ajaxaction/clea...')
    1 /framework/base/CApplication.php(162): CWebApplication->processRequest()
    2 /index.php(11): CApplication->run()
    3 {main}
    REQUEST_URI=/ajaxaction/clearbasket

Comment: думаю, проблема в названии контроллера: переименуйте его в AjaxactionController

Comment: А жесть!

Точняк, трабл решился. Но почему в таком виде нельзя писать название файла. Сам контроллер оставил без изменений

>class AjaxActionController extends CController

а файл переименовал

>AjaxActionController.php

в

>AjaxactionController.php

Comment: Подскажу источник проблем. Различия в файловых системах. Вероятно в линуксе ext2, ext3 или ext4 - это регистрочувствительная файловая система. Fat32 ее не поддеррживает вовсе, а NTFS поддерживает, но по умолчанию отключено. Сам столкнулся, когда заливал проект на сервер на линукс. Причем пришлось исправлять даже имена таблиц.  
П.С. Можно попробовать в url-manager добавить 'caseSensitive'=>false.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй переименовать контроллер, вероятно на сервере стоит какой-то фильтр.

Comment: К сожалению переименовать контроллер было бы просто, но на нём висит куча всего, и искать в коде где встречается его вызов, достаточно громоздкий процесс. т.к. используются правила которые в добавок перенаправляются по разным роутам. что увеличивает трудозатраты на перепись названия контрола

Comment: тоже \+ поставлю, ибо в нужную сторону копнули, почти.